# Building custom Caffe layer in python

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

After parsing many links regarding building Caffe layers in Python i still have difficulties in understanding few concepts. Can please someone clarify them?

- Blobs and weights python structure for network is explained here: [Finding gradient of a Caffe conv-filter with regards to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324739/finding-gradient-of-a-caffe-conv-filter-with-regards-to-input).
- Network and Solver structure is explained here: [Cheat sheet for caffe / pycaffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379878/cheat-sheet-for-caffe-pycaffe).
- Example of defining python layer is here: [pyloss.py on git](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py).
- Layer tests here: [test layer on  git](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer_with_param_str.py).
- Development of new layers for C++ is described here: [git wiki](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development).

What I am still missing is:

1. `setup()` method: what I should do here? Why in example I should compare the lenght of 'bottom' param with '2'? Why it should be 2? It seems not a batch size because its arbitrary? And bottom as I understand is blob, and then the first dimension is batch size?
2. `reshape()` method: as I understand 'bottom' input param is blob of below layer, and 'top' param is blob of upper layer, and I need to reshape top layer according to output shape of my calculations with forward pass. But why do I need to do this every forward pass if these shapes do not change from pass to pass, only weights change?
3. `reshape` and `forward` methods have 0 indexes for 'top' input param used. Why would I need to use `top[0].data=...` or `top[0].input=...` instead of `top.data=...` and `top.input=...`? Whats this index about? If we do not use other part of this top list, why it is exposed in this way? I can suspect its or C++ backbone coincidence, but it would be good to know exactly.
4. `reshape()` method, line with:

   ```
   if bottom[0].count != bottom[1].count
   ```

   what I do here? why its dimension is 2 again? And what I am counting here? Why both part of blobs (0 and 1) should be equal in amount of some members (`count`)?
5. `forward()` method, what I define by this line:

   ```
   self.diff[...] = bottom[0].data - bottom[1].data
   ```

   When it is used after forward path if I define it? Can we just use

   ```
   diff = bottom[0].data - bottom[1].data
   ```

   instead to count loss later in this method, without assigning to `self`, or its done with some purpose?
6. `backward()` method: what's this about: `for i in range(2):`? Why again range is 2?
7. `backward()` method, `propagate_down` parameter: why it is defined? I mean if its True, gradient should be assigned to `bottom[X].diff` as I see, but why would someone call method which would do nothing with `propagate_down = False`, if it just do nothing and still cycling inside?

I'm sorry if those questions are too obvious, I just wasn't able to find a good guide to understand them and asking for help here.

Comment: Dont forget to make pycaffe with flag WITH_PYTHON_LAYERS=1, see [here](http://chrischoy.github.io/research/caffe-python-layer/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You asked a lot of questions here, I'll give you some highlights and pointers that I hope will clarify matters for you. I will not explicitly answer all your questions.

It seems like you are most confused about the the difference between a blob and a layer's input/output. Indeed most of the layers has a *single* blob as input and a *single* blob as output, but it is not always the case. Consider a loss layer: it has *two* inputs: predictions and ground truth labels. So, in this case `bottom` is a vector of length **2**(!) with `bottom[0]` being a (4-D) blob representing predictions, while `bottom[1]` is another blob with the labels. Thus, when constructing such a layer you must ascertain that you have exactly (hard coded) 2 input blobs (see e.g., `ExactNumBottomBlobs()` in [`AccuracyLayer`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/loss_layers.hpp#L40) definition).

The same goes for `top` blobs as well: indeed in most cases there is a single `top` for each layer, but it's not always the case (see e.g., [`AccuracyLayer`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/loss_layers.hpp#L40)). Therefore, `top` is also a *vector* of 4-D blobs, one for each `top` of the layer. Most of the time there would be a single element in that vector, but sometimes you might find more than one.

I believe this covers your questions 1,3,4 and 6.

As of `reshape()` (Q.2) this function is not called every forward pass, it is called only when net is setup to allocate space for inputs/outputs and params.
Occasionally, you might want to change input size for your net (e.g., for detection nets) then you need to call `reshape()` for all layers of the net to accommodate the new input size.

As for `propagate_down` parameter (Q.7): since a layer may have more than one `bottom` you would need, in principle, to pass the gradient to *all* `bottom`s during backprop. However, what is the meaning of a gradient to the `label` bottom of a loss layer? There are cases when you do not want to propagate to *all* `bottom`s: this is what this flag is for. (here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349475/1714410) with a loss layer with three `bottom`s that expect gradient to all of them).

For more information, see [this `"Python"` layer tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410).

Comment: Thank you, Shai, that makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it should be 2?**

That specific gist is talking about the Euclidian loss layer. Euclidian loss is the mean square error between **2** vectors. Hence there must be 2 vectors in the input blob to this layer. The length of each vector must be same because it is element-wise difference. You can see this check in the **reshape** method.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be comment