# how to get learning rate or iteration times when define new layer in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to change the loss calculation method in loss layer when the  iteration times reach a certain number.
In order to realize it I think I need to get the current learning rate or iteration times, then I use `if` phrase to choose changing loss calculation method or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a member variable in **Caffe class** to save the current learning rate or iteration times and access it in the layer where you want.

For example, to get the current iteration times where you want you need to make 3 key modifications(for simplification):

1. In [common.hpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/common.hpp):

   ```
     class Caffe {
       public:
         static Caffe& Get();

         ...//Some other public members

         //Returns the current iteration times
         inline static int current_iter() { return Get().cur_iter_; }
         //Sets the current iteration times
         inline static void set_cur_iter(int iter) { Get().cur_iter_ = iter; }

       protected:

         //The variable to save the current itertion times
         int cur_iter_;

         ...//Some other protected members
     }
   ```
2. In [solver.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp):

   ```
     template <typename Dtype>
     void Solver<Dtype>::Step(int iters) {

       ...

       while (iter_ < stop_iter) {
         Caffe::set_cur_iter(iter_ );
         ...//Left Operations
       }
     }
   ```
3. The place where you want to access the current iteration times:

   ```
     template <typename Dtype>
     void SomeLayer<Dtype>::some_func() {
       int current_iter = Caffe::current_iter();
       ...//Operations you want
     }
   ```

Comment: How about the method given by Shai? I think it more easier to realize, only add a variable as counter.

Comment: Shai 's method is also very easy and good. But you should note that if you want to continue your stoped training from a snapshot by "caffe train --snapshot="xxx.solverstate", you should make sure that the counter in the IterCounterLossLayer will also be copied from the corresponding trained caffemodel. In this case, you should use a blob_ to be the counter in IterCounterLossLayer to make sure that it will be copied @mrbrant

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no direct access from within a python layer to the solver's iteration count and the learning rate.
However, you can keep a counter of your own

```
import caffe

class IterCounterLossLayer(caffe.Layer):
def setup(self, bottom, top):
  # do your setup here...
  self.iter_counter = 0  # setup a counter

def reshape(self, bottom, top):
  # reshape code here...
  # loss output is scalar
  top[0].reshape(1)

def forward(self, bottom, top):
  if self.iter_counter < 1000:
    # some way of computing the loss
    # ...
  else:
    # another way
    # ...
  self.iter_counter += 1  # increment, you may consider incrementing by bottom[0].shape[0] the batch size...

def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
  if self.iter_counter < 1000:
    # gradients need to fit the loss
    # ...
  else:
    # another way
    # ...
```

Comment: Do you know how to define the layer by keeping a counter use c++ language not python? I am not familiar with python to define layer.

Comment: @mrbrant it's very easy to build a layer in python. see [this post](http://chrischoy.github.io/research/caffe-python-layer/) for example. You can find more details here at SO, for example [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33797142/1714410)

Comment: @mrbrant if you insist on writing in C++, you will notice that each layer is a class you can add a member variable to be the counter and increment it in the `forward` method.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try it. @Shai

Answer (score 0):

To get iteration, you can use my count_layer as a bottom layer of your custom layer, with which you can benefit from following aspects:

1. When you finetune with weights, the iteration number continues from the weights you save.
2. Have a modular implementation.
3. No need to change existing caffe codes.

train_val.prototxt

```
layer {
  name: "iteration"
  top: "iteration"
  type: "Count"
}
```

count_layer.hpp

```
#ifndef CAFFE_COUNT_LAYER_HPP_
#define CAFFE_COUNT_LAYER_HPP_

#include <vector>

#include "caffe/common.hpp"
#include "caffe/filler.hpp"
#include "caffe/layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/util/math_functions.hpp"

namespace caffe {

template <typename Dtype>
class CountLayer : public Layer<Dtype> {
 public:
   explicit CountLayer(const LayerParameter& param)
     : Layer<Dtype>(param), delta_(1) {}
  virtual void LayerSetUp(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {

    if (this->blobs_.size() > 0) {
      LOG(INFO) << "Skipping parameter initialization";
    } else {
      this->blobs_.resize(1);
      this->blobs_[0].reset(new Blob<Dtype>());
      if (this->layer_param_.count_param().has_shape()){
        this->blobs_[0]->Reshape(this->layer_param_.count_param().shape());
      } else{
        this->blobs_[0]->Reshape(vector<int>{1, 1});
      }
      shared_ptr<Filler<Dtype> > base_filler(GetFiller<Dtype>(
        this->layer_param_.count_param().base_filler()));
      base_filler->Fill(this->blobs_[0].get());
    }
    top[0]->Reshape(this->blobs_[0]->shape());

    string name = this->layer_param().name();
    if (name == ""){
      name = "Count";
    }
    if (this->layer_param_.param_size() <= 0){
      LOG(INFO) << "Layer " << name << "'s decay_mult has been set to 0";
      this->layer_param_.add_param()->set_decay_mult(Dtype(0));
    } else if (!this->layer_param_.param(0).has_decay_mult()){
      LOG(INFO) << "Layer " << name << "'s decay_mult has been set to 0";
      this->layer_param_.mutable_param(0)->set_decay_mult(0);
    } 

    delta_ = Dtype(this->layer_param_.count_param().delta());
    //this make top start from base and make finetune correct
    caffe_add_scalar(this->blobs_[0]->count(), -delta_, this->blobs_[0]->mutable_cpu_data()); 
  }
  virtual void Reshape(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) { }
  virtual inline const char* type() const { return "Parameter"; }
  virtual inline int ExactNumBottomBlobs() const { return 0; }
  virtual inline int ExactNumTopBlobs() const { return 1; }

 protected:
  virtual void Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
    caffe_add_scalar(this->blobs_[0]->count(), delta_, this->blobs_[0]->mutable_cpu_data());
    top[0]->ShareData(*(this->blobs_[0]));
    top[0]->ShareDiff(*(this->blobs_[0]));
  }
  virtual void Backward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top,
      const vector<bool>& propagate_down, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom)
  { 
  }

  private:
    Dtype delta_;
};

}  // namespace caffe

#endif
```

caffe_layer.cpp

```
#include "caffe/layers/count_layer.hpp"

namespace caffe {

INSTANTIATE_CLASS(CountLayer);
REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(Count);

}  // namespace caffe
```

caffe.proto

```
optional CountParameter count_param = 666;
...
message CountParameter {
  optional BlobShape shape = 1;
  optional FillerParameter base_filler = 2; // The filler for the base
  optional float delta = 3 [default = 1];
}
```