# Trying to understand custom loss layer in caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have seen one can define a custom loss layer for example EuclideanLoss in caffe like this:

```
import caffe
import numpy as np


    class EuclideanLossLayer(caffe.Layer):
        """
        Compute the Euclidean Loss in the same manner as the C++ 
EuclideanLossLayer
        to demonstrate the class interface for developing layers in Python.
        """

        def setup(self, bottom, top):
            # check input pair
            if len(bottom) != 2:
                raise Exception("Need two inputs to compute distance.")

        def reshape(self, bottom, top):
            # check input dimensions match
            if bottom[0].count != bottom[1].count:
                raise Exception("Inputs must have the same dimension.")
            # difference is shape of inputs
            self.diff = np.zeros_like(bottom[0].data, dtype=np.float32)
            # loss output is scalar
            top[0].reshape(1)

        def forward(self, bottom, top):
            self.diff[...] = bottom[0].data - bottom[1].data
            top[0].data[...] = np.sum(self.diff**2) / bottom[0].num / 2.

        def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
            for i in range(2):
                if not propagate_down[i]:
                    continue
                if i == 0:
                    sign = 1
                else:
                    sign = -1
                bottom[i].diff[...] = sign * self.diff / bottom[i].num
```

However, I have a few question regarding that code:

If I want to customise this layer and change the computation of the loss in this line:

```
top[0].data[...] = np.sum(self.diff**2) / bottom[0].num / 2.
```

Lets say to:

```
channelsAxis = bottom[0].data.shape[1]
self.diff[...] = np.sum(bottom[0].data, axis=channelAxis) - np.sum(bottom[1].data, axis=channelAxis)
top[0].data[...] = np.sum(self.diff**2) / bottom[0].num / 2.
```

How do I have to change the backward function? For EuclideanLoss it is:

```
bottom[i].diff[...] = sign * self.diff / bottom[i].num
```

How does it have to look for my described loss?

What is the sign for?

Comment: what weight and bias is there in Euclidean loss??

Comment: I am sorry, I confused myself a little bit as well. I have updated the question! @Shai

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797142/1714410

Comment: `top[0].data[...] = euclidean_weight * euclidean + other_weight * other` is not the right way to do this. You can have a **regular** Euclidean loss layer with `loss_weight: euclidean_weight` and your own `"OtherLoss"` layer with `loss_weight: other_weight`.

Comment: Okay, so if I want to create my own loss do I need to change any lines in the backward function or is it sufficient enough to just edit that one line where the actual calculation is done? @Shai

Comment: you **MUST** change `backward()` as well: it must perform the gradient computation for the **specific** loss you are designing. Otherwise you backprop is meaningless.

Comment: Okay, and how has the backward() function to be updated related to the loss calculation? I have given you an example for my loss calculation, but how would you update the backward computation? @Shai

Comment: your `other` is zero. it has to be a **scalar**. `bottom[0].diff` = d(other)/d(bottom[0])`

Comment: What do you mean by is zero? My other is a subtraction of a sum --> scalar.  So there should not be a problem? and what do you mean by d()? Could you edit / improve your question? Why do I not need the sign checking? @Shai

Comment: what is `shape` of `bottom[0].data`? what is `channelAxis`? if you `sum` only over `channelAxis` how do you expect to get a scalar? What with all other dimensions?

Comment: Bottom[0].data has the same shape as for EuclideanLoss channelAxis is the axis for the channels. I assume that my bottom blob is of shape (height, width, channels)? What I basically want to do is to compute a loss of the difference of the sum of my channels: loss = (y1 = xg1 + xg2 + ... + xgn) - (y = xi1 + xi2 + ... + xin). Where xg1 = channel ground truth 1 and xi1 = channel result 1. Could you help me with that? @Shai

Comment: you forgot the batch size as the fourth dimension of the blob (aka `bottom[i].num`).

Comment: just difference? your net will try to maximize `x` - the larger `sum(x)` the lower the diff would be (you can have `loss = -inf` in theory). does not sound like a good loss.

Comment: So bottom[i].num = batch_size? and bottom[i].data = (height, width, channels)? @Shai

Comment: `bottom[i].data` is an `np.array` of *`shape`* `(num, channel, height, width)`.  `bottom[i].data.shape[0] == bottom[i].num`

Comment: Yes loss = sum(y1 - y2) / some_value.  To make it smaller I will add some_value. Isn't that basically almost the same as EuclideanLoss, since I take the difference and divide by something? EuclideanLoss takes the difference and squares it and then divides it as well? @Shai

Comment: euclidean loss has zero as a lower bound, while your loss does not have a lower bound. This is quite a NOT the same.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question. Could you try and make it have a lower bound? I think you know what I want do do now, am I right? @Shai

Comment: What I basically want to do is: EuclideanLoss, but I want to reduce the channels to 1 by adding all the values up in the height and width dimension. DO you understand me? @Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can be a very educating exercise to implement the [loss you are after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674480/trying-to-understand-custom-loss-layer-in-caffe?noredirect=1#comment76339891_44674480) as a `"Python"` layer, you can get the same loss using *existing* layers. All you need is to add a [`"Reduction"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reduction.html) layer for each of your blobs before calling the regular `"EuclideanLoss"` layer:

```
layer {
  type: "Reduction"
  name: "rx1"
  bottom: "x1"
  top: "rx1"
  reduction_param { axis: 1 operation: SUM }
} 
layer {
  type: "Reduction"
  name: "rx2"
  bottom: "x2"
  top: "rx2"
  reduction_param { axis: 1 operation: SUM }
} 
layer {
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  name: "loss"
  bottom: "rx1"
  bottom: "rx2"
  top: "loss"
}
```

---

**Update:**
Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674480/trying-to-understand-custom-loss-layer-in-caffe/44678066?noredirect=1#comment76368632_44678066), if you only want to sum over the channel dimension and leave all other dimensions unchanged, you can use fixed 1x1 conv (as you suggested):

```
layer {
  type: "Convolution"
  name: "rx1"
  bottom: "x1"
  top: "rx1"
  param { lr_mult: 0 decay_mult: 0 } # make this layer *fixed*
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
    kernel_size: 1
    bias_term: 0  # no need for bias
    weight_filler: { type: "constant" value: 1 } # sum
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that is perfect! And now I can easily add weight_loss and have two EuclideanLosses am I right?

Comment: @thigi exactly. getting to know existing layers can allow you to be quite lazy ;)

Comment: I have thought about the solution and it is wrong! It sums over all values rather than over all channels values. So but I want to create the sum like this: y = channel1 + channel2 + channel3 ... channelN. So the sum over the channels, rather than all axes. Could you help me with that? I think one can use a Convolution layer with `num_output = 1` and `weight_filler = constant, value = 1` would that be correct? Could you update your answer?

Comment: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693043/is-there-a-layer-that-is-able-to-sum-over-all-channels-in-caffe)

Comment: Okay, thank you! What I do not understand, if the input lets say has 16 channels, how does the summation work? I thought caffe was treating each channel separately in convolution layers? Could you quickly extend your answer with a short expalanation? That would just be for a better understanding :)  @Shai