# Which is right tripletLoss backpropagation formula?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I saw [What's the triplet loss back propagation gradient formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330779/whats-the-triplet-loss-back-propagation-gradient-formula/33349475#33349475)
For gradient, anchor is `n-p`, positive is `p-a` and negative is `a-n`.
But from 80 line to 92 line of [`tripletLossLayer`](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/triplet_loss_layer.cpp) is different to this.
Namely, for gradient anchor is `p - n` and positive is `p - a`.
which is really right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines 80-92 in [`triplet_loss_layer.cpp`](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/triplet_loss_layer.cpp#L80-L92) are part of `forward_cpu` function - that is the actual loss computation and NOT the gradient computation.

The gradient is computed in [`backward_cpu`](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/triplet_loss_layer.cpp#L116-L171), where you can see that each `bottom` is assigned its `diff` according to the derivation presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349475/1714410).

Comment: thanks for your help.
I am training the tripletloss layer for face verification.
GoogleNet or VggNet talked performance is boosted using this layer, but i am not.
I want your help