# Face Recognition based on Deep Learning (Siamese Architecture)

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I want to use pre-trained model for the face identification. I try to use Siamese architecture which requires a few number of images. Could you give me any trained model which I can change for the Siamese architecture? How can I change the network model which I can put two images to find their similarities (I do not want to create image based on the tutorial [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/siamese))? I only want to use the system for real time application. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you can use [this model](https://github.com/AlfredXiangWu/face_verification_experiment), described in [*Xiang Wu, Ran He, Zhenan Sun, Tieniu Tan* **A Light CNN for Deep Face Representation with Noisy Labels** (arXiv 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02683) as a a strating point for your experiments.

As for the Siamese network, what you are trying to earn is a mapping from a face image into some high dimensional vector space, in which distances between points reflects (dis)similarity between faces.
To do so, you only need *one* network that gets a face as an input and produce a high-dim vector as an output.
However, to train this *single* network using the Siamese approach, you are going to duplicate it: creating two instances of the *same* net (you need to explicitly link the weights of the two copies). During training you are going to provide pairs of faces to the nets: one to each copy, then the single loss layer on top of the two copies can compare the high-dimensional vectors representing the two faces and compute a loss according to a "same/not same" label associated with this pair.
Hence, you only need the duplication for the training. In test time (`'deploy'`) you are going to have a *single* net providing you with a semantically meaningful high dimensional representation of faces.

For a more advance Siamese architecture and loss see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33330779/1714410).

---

On the other hand, you might want to consider the approach described in [*Oren Tadmor, Yonatan Wexler, Tal Rosenwein, Shai Shalev-Shwartz, Amnon Shashua* **Learning a Metric Embedding for Face Recognition using the Multibatch Method** (arXiv 2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07270). This approach is more efficient and easy to implement than pair-wise losses over image pairs.